# Azure Devops API Release test results

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've got a couple of questions.
I'm trying to use the Azure DevOps API to get the test results from a release, the release has multiple tests that are listed separately in the test runs i.e they have different RunID numbers. What URI do I use to get the actual test results the way it's displayed if you click on the test results from within the release pipeline. If this cannot be done, how do I get all of the test results relating to one release and output the fail and success total of them added together.

The other way I've looked at this is to get all of the RunID's from the tests and filter through them matching the release name in the Run to the release name in the release pipeline, but seeing as there are over 1248 runs I don't want to do that.
I'm having trouble getting the run query working I don't know how to set the minLastUpdatedDate={minLastUpdatedDate} or the
maxLastUpdatedDate={maxLastUpdatedDate} are set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

The documentation doesn't specify the format apart from date-time!
Some examples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Is DateTime format the main problem here?
"yyyy-MM-dd" and
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
both worked for me, I guess more would too.

Example:

```
https://[...]/_apis/test/runs?minLastUpdatedDate=2019-07-02&maxLastUpdatedDate=07/05/2019 16:16:11&releaseIds=243&releaseEnvIds=2899&api-version=5.0
```

Comment: Then how to map the test runs to the test stages (environments)? I can query the test runs; and I also can query the Release's stages (environments) but how do I know which run is for which stage/environment?